# Play 2.2.2 / com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.2: not found on Heroku

Tags: heroku, sbt, playframework-2.2

All works well with Play 2.2.1.
However, when upgrading to Play 2.2.2 and deploying to Heroku, process warns about:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.2: not found
       unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.10;2.2.2: not found
       unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#filters-helpers_2.10;2.2.2: not found
       unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.10;2.2.2: not found
       unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.10;2.2.2: not found
```

I don't figure out why..I just updated the plugins.sbt to:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2") //just added 2.2.2 instead of 2.2.1
```

and upgraded sbt to 0.13.0.

Shouldn't this dependency be downloaded without explicit set on the Build.scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I managed to do the trick by adding this line, before my series of `resolvers +=`:

```
resolvers := Seq("typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/")
```

If it can help some people coming across the same issue :)