# Error: Deploying a HelloWorld application to Heroku (Play 2.3.2)

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to deploy a hello world application to [heroku.com](http://www.heroku.com).

I followed the steps on: [playframework.com](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionHeroku) but it doesn't work.

All steps I made can be viewed here:[pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/0sFer1YQ).. Which steps am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure why you get the error, but based on [this google groups question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/nVJu1ywtHW4) and this [similar question about unresolved dependencies in heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157135/play-2-2-2-com-typesafe-playplay-2-102-2-2-not-found-on-heroku), you could try updating your Build.scala as mentioned. Worth also asking heroku support if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved, after I updated play, sbt (..) using `brew update`.
Now I can deploy a new project with these commands ():

```
heroku login
play new appName
cd appName
git init .
git add -A
git commit -m "init"
heroku create
git push heroku master
```